# Load a class inherted from doctrine model using doctrine_query

Tags: php, doctrine

I have 2 classes

```
Class form extends Baseform
{
        /* this is doctrine model class */
}
```

Below is the Inherited Class

```
Class admissionForm extends form
{
        /* this is inherited class */
}
```

I am trying to query database using **doctrine_query** and search for **form** model. Based on my results I want objects of **admissionForm** class instead of **form** class.

I have tried using **serialize** and **unserialize** functions of doctrine like below but it replace **$admissionFormObj** with an instance of form class.

```
$admissionFormObj->unserialize($formObj->serialize());
```

Comment: The `form` model confused me a bit ..

Comment: I corrected the form class. It is actually inherited from Baseform class which is further inherited from Doctrine_Record

Comment: I still don't understand what you want to do.